# What is Crystal Reports' DateTime.MinValue?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, report

I want to know the minimum value of the Crystal Reports datetime datatype.

I know the minimum for .NET and SQLServer, but I cannot find the minimum for Crystal Reports anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

larger than everyone else...something like 1-01-01 to 9999-12-31

You will get the error message "Dates must be between year 1 and year 9999"

What do you need it for? I usually just use #1900-01-01#, if I need a base date for date arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it depend on the underlying data source?